# Built a react native app for ios, i cant push to appstore, xcode not showing distribute app options

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store

1. When i go to window > organizer > Archives and select an archive, instead of "distribute **app**" i get "distribute **content**", see capture

[image: ac]

2. Then when i click on distribute content since its the only option available instead of getting export options to app store i get only to options that ask me to export/save an archive to my computer, see capture.

[image]

My XCode version is 10.1, also i have done all configurations from setting my apple id, adding keys / certificates, etc.

I am stuck at this stage, Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are not archiving the app target. You’re archiving the wrong target.

Comment: @matt you were right, it was this simple. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I’ll give it as an answer.

Comment: please visit this link for a possible solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71453125/10590417

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not archiving the app target. You’re archiving the wrong target.

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow below steps:

1) Make sure that you are a select device as **Generic iOS Device** on top Left corner

[image: Step:1]

2) Click on **Product** on top menu

3) Click on **Archive**

4) After successfully Archive, You will get below window and click on **Upload to App Store**
[image: Upload to App Store]

5) Select your proper apple account and provisional profile and click on next.

You are done.