# Distribute content instead of distribute app in xcode 10.1

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am trying to upload a build to the app store but I am getting the issue that it builds successfully but `Distribute App` does not appears there. It displays like `Distribute Content`.

Image:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55467829/xcode-10-1-doesnt-show-distribute-app-option-when-archiving-cant-archive

Comment: I already tried this solution but its not working for me

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by going to 'Build Settings' > 'All' and setting the value of 'Skip Install' to 'No'

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Making sure to have below Build Settings resolved issue for me :

> - "Skip Install" should always be No for all Application Targets.
> - "Skip Install" should always be Yes for all other targets(Includes    AppClip, Frameworks, Watch Targets).

Answer (score 1):

I did fixed this issue now. I have just make changes in workspace setting as like below:
1) Goto file -> WorkSpace Setting
2) Make changes in Shared Workspace setting as => Build Systems -> New Build System(Default)
3) Also Make changes in Per-user Workspace setting as => Build Systems -> New Build System

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem by keep "Skip install" of Runner No and "Skip install" of Frame work or 3rd parties is Yes

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the old answers, I have solved the problem by keeping "Skip install" of frameworks to false.

But one thing special is that, `runner` and `framework` in my project are in different schemes. Hope the picture will help new comers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can here after I ran into the same problem. The project I am working on also has multiple schemes, just like some others are saying. The solution for me was not any of the previously mentioned.

It all had to do with the `RUN_DOCUMENTATION_COMPILER` build option, also known as the "Build Documentation During 'Build'" listed under "Documentation Compiler - options".

This option was set to `YES` in my case, for both 'Debug' and 'Release'. The solution here is simple. Set the `RUN_DOCUMENTATION_COMPILER` to `NO`. Do this at least for the 'Release' build, it would not matter for the 'Debug'.

Hope this has helped! When you've created an archive, it should now say "Distribute App".