# Xcode showing distribute content instead of distribute App. Xcode 13.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build

I recently updated to Xcode 13.2.1, I want to release an app to the app store but when I do Product => Archive, it shows Distribute Content instead of Distribute App. I checked my build settings, it has skip install to No. Any idea how to fix it.

Here is the screenshot of the build settings.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distribute content instead of distribute app in xcode 10.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112185/distribute-content-instead-of-distribute-app-in-xcode-10-1)

Answer (score 0):

For posterity:

I'm using Xcode 14.2.
I also had this issue. In newer versions of Xcode, the `Info.plist` file is no longer just a file on disk but saved in the project files. There is a somewhat "newer" key found in the project called `GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE`. This was set to `YES` on my TARGET to generated the Info file. I turned it off due to a bug in `agvtool`. Suddenly, I could not "Distribute App", but only "Distribute Content".

I assume that Archiving detects whether all Info data is in place before distribution. Since the Info file wasn't being generated, it didn't provide the option to "Distribute App". Turning on "Generate Info.plist file" in the project settings fixed the problem.