# Xcode: Distributes App don't show when archiving

Tags: xcode, macos

I had the issue, my project included many small projects combined. And when I archived my project, the xcode didn't show "**distribute app**" (it showed "**Distribute content**").
[image]

I still tried many solutions as below, but this issue still occurred:

1, Choose Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Build -> remove other targets or unselect archive checkbox.

2, Choose Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Build -> unselect at Find Implicit Dependencies
[image]

3, Choose Build Setting, then change Skip Install to YES.
[image]
Can Anyone help me resolving this issue?

Same issue: [Xcode 10.1 doesn't show 'distribute app' option when archiving, can't archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55467829/xcode-10-1-doesnt-show-distribute-app-option-when-archiving-cant-archive)

Thanks.

Comment: same issue. nothing can solve it.